# Why can't I connect to an ad-hoc wireless network on a Windows 7 system?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am using HP Compaq 6735b with 12.04 on it.

I am trying to connect to an ad hoc network set up on a Windows 7 system. However, my Ubuntu is giving me lots of problem. It doesn't always show the wireless networks and if it decides to show me the networks, I can't connect to the ad hoc network.

Please help someone.

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience in windows ad hoc network types are weak and unstable . if you want to create a wireless network that other computers or devices be able to connect to it and use internet I mean if you want to share internet via wireless in windows use connectify .
it's a software that you are able to create wire or wireless network and share internet via this networks . I hope this answer was helpfull